# Hooks other than WH_KEYBOARD_LL and WH_MOUSE_LL fail to catch message from another process

Tags: c, windows

I have tried different types of hooks using [SetWindowsHookEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa) API, but only WH_KEYBOARD_LL and WH_MOUSE_LL seems to be truly catching messages sent to whichever process, which should be the situation for C#, not C.

For example, after setting up WH_CALLWNDPROC handle,

```
HHOOK WindowMessageHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(
    WH_CALLWNDPROC,
    OnWindowMessage,
    DllHandle,
    0
);
```

with this test callback function in dll,

```
LRESULT __declspec(dllexport) OnWindowMessage(int nCode, WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam){
    static int count = 0;
    printf("Window message. %d\n", count);
    count += 1;
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode,wParam,lParam);
}
```

it catches messages sent to window created by the very same process, only when it is focused. On the other hand, nothing prints when I move mouse in, click inside, or resize window of any other application on my PC.

Comment: As far as I know, Windows made an exception for those hooks specifically. But more generally you have to execute your code in the same process in other to pick up messages. Hence "DLL injection" and other such hacks.

Comment: @Lundin Ok, I've understood DLL injection as the general way. To make it clear, by those hooks do you mean the two low-level hooks ending with LL? If so, are there any other hooks permitted by Windows to directly intercept other processes' messages?

Comment: Your hook code is running in the context of each process, thus printf is writing to stdout of each process. Given these are GUI processes they usually don't have stdout setup to write anywhere. You need to log to a file or do some kind of IPC back to your process to see the lot messages.